# how to match only 2 digits before point and only one or two digits after point

Tags: regex

for example if I have 90.59 i must match "90.59" if i have 90.5 i must match "90.5" but if i have 090.59 i  should not match anything. Only two digits before point and two or one digits after point

Comment: you are treating this as a string?

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you mean to say that you want to match only those strings that have one *or* two numbers before the point *and* one *or* two numbers after the point, but not any strings with three or more numbers either before or after the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex `(?<![0-9])([0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{1,2}(?![0-9]))`

Comment: yes but i have text before digits this is my regex \d{2}\.+\d{1,2} but match from 004.2 => 04.2

Answer (score 1):

You can use word boundaries for avoiding partial match of digits in a larger number using this regex,

```
\b\d{2}\.\d{1,2}\b
```

**[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pWOKz8/1)**